# VBA Excel delete row if one cell of the row starts with certain string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 2 columns which contain specifications for some components.
Basically, I want to delete an entire row if the initial letter of two specified columns is different from S.

My table looks something like this

[image]

I want to delete every row if column "from device" AND "to device" Begins with G or C (or, in more specific words, if either column "from" and "to" begins with S, keep the entire row), my code is the following:

```
Sub FilterData2()

Dim rcount As Long

With Sheet3
    rcount = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("E1:E" & rcount)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(5), "C*") > 0 Then
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="C*"
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End If
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(5), "G*") > 0 Then
             .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="G*"
             .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
             .AutoFilter
        End If
       End With
   End With

End Sub
```

However, this only works for column E, meaning that if column G contains a cell starting with S and column E doesnt, the row would still be deleted and I want to keep the row.

Any suggestions ? thanks!

Comment: You are using your If Statements just on column E `With Range("E1:E" & rcount)`

Comment: I tried using instr but it deleted almost everything because almost every cell contains a "C" or a "G" and I don't know how to specify that i want it to be just for the first character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine your if statements in VBA.

Using the AND modifier:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(5), "C*") > 0 AND Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(5), "G*") > 0 Then
```

Similarly, you can use an OR modifier:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(5), "C*") > 0 OR Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(5), "G*") > 0 Then
```

To apply this to your code, where you just want to see if the cell's contents start with S in either from or to:

```
Dim rcount As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim strE, strG As String

With Sheets("Sheet3")
    rcount = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = rcount to 2 Step -1
        strE = Left(.Cells(i, "E").Value, 1)
        strG = Left(.Cells(i, "G").Value, 1)
        If strE = "S" Or strG = "S" Then
        Else
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

That should simplify the process significantly.

Comment: This worked fine! I was trying to use Left as a friend recommended it but I was still figuring out the syntax. Thank you!

Comment: @JeanCarlo no worries.  I might recommend one change, as even I missed this when working through the code:  *rcount= .cells( .rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row*   I missed that the .Rows.Count didn't also specifythe Sheets("Sheet3").